# Spring Interpolation String Exception

Tags: spring

Условно есть файлс c текстами ошибок парами ключ значение,
`exception.not.found=Не найдено что-то...`

и есть у меня `ResponseException()`, могу сделать поле типа String и повесить аннотацию `@Value("${exception.not.found}")`
Как сделать чтобы можно было интерполировать текст в исключение без поля?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `getProperty("id")` из класса `PropertyResolve`